# Sonata and export csv and xls

Tags: csv, export, sonata

I have a problem with exportation of list in sonata:

If I build the CSV file, with office 2016 i see a wrong table (because the delimiter is "`,`")

If I use XLS file, I can see the file, but office show an alert before open.

my questions are:

1. is possible change delimiter of CSV?
2. is possible export XLSX file from the same menu? (in image)

[image]

I found a link but I don't  understand to use 
https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/2707

thank you

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using SonataAdminBundle 3.x.:

> is possible change delimiter of CSV?

Yes, it is possible though you have to make some updates. Exporter is class from SonataCoreBundle but it has been deprecated (see [Exporter source](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataCoreBundle/blob/3.x/src/Exporter/Exporter.php#L21)). For exporting purposes you should use separate [Exporter](https://github.com/sonata-project/exporter) class from SonataExporterBundle.

Also I have to mention that default SonataCoreBundle exporter has CSV delimiter hardcoded (see [code](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataCoreBundle/blob/3.x/src/Exporter/Exporter.php#L60)).

**Here is guide how to use SonataExporterBundle with SonataAdminBundle:**

1. [Install](https://github.com/sonata-project/exporter/blob/1.x/docs/reference/installation.rst) sonata-project/exporter library via Composer (you can omit dev-master part).
2. [Register](https://github.com/sonata-project/exporter/blob/1.x/docs/reference/symfony.rst#registering-the-bundle) SonataExporterBundle with Symfony (it doesn't really matter if it is before or after SonataAdminBundle).
3. Add this to `config.yml`:

```
sonata_exporter:
    writers:
        csv:
            delimiter: ";"
```

4. Clear cache:

```bash
php bin/console cache:clear
```

You can adjust configuration some more by the way. Check [Configuration](https://github.com/sonata-project/exporter/blob/1.x/src/Bridge/Symfony/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php#L32) class for more options.

> is possible export XLSX file from the same menu? (in image)

I'm afraid this is not possible now. Both SonataCoreBundle and SonataExporterBundle exporters have only CSV, JSON, XLS and XML writers right now. You'd have to write your own XLSX export functionality or find bundle where it's implemented (I haven't found one).